# ajax POST requests working in incognito but not in chrome - 404 Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

```
Below is my code:

function editUser(ext,randomUID){

        var csrfParameter = $("meta[name='_csrf_parameter']").attr("content");
        var csrfHeader = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
        var csrfToken = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
        var headers = {};
        headers[csrfHeader] = csrfToken;


        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "api/v1/user/editUser/"+randomUID+"/"+ext,
            headers:headers,
            success : function(response) {
                    // Do something
}

Above works perfectly in Incognito mode but not in chrome. It always gives me 404() not found. I have seen many threads regarding cache control for POST requests. But none of them worked, by default cache control is handled by spring security and for all POST requests I see in console response headers as below:

Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Sun, 08 Mar 2020 09:41:48 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Server: MAM
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=bcd84bb3-a709-4876-aa6a-0e4b3404a58e
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=bcd84bb3-a709-4876-aa6a-0e4b3404a58e
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Please let me know if I'm missing something here, besides, the app is deployed in weblogic- Do we need to do further settings in weblogic console.

Comment: Use a relative path in your `url` or a full path with hostname

Comment: agree to Anurag + you could just add a random query-parameter to check if its cache-related for example just add ` +'m=1337'` to url

Comment: Thanks Anurag and Smith for the prompt response, i will try the above suggested and post back with the output.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with similar issue, after updating Chrome. The problem was solved when I switched from http to https

Comment: you propably ran into "HSTS" which is enabed by sending the `Strict-Transport-Security` Header and means that it will force https . you can only delete this rule in chrome by visiting  `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` and then enter your hostname in "delete domain" section